# HTML in Database

Tags: php, html

I am trying to read a html file which is a plain page with nothing but and  tags in it. I'm using a function to return what is between each  tag . . I can echo this to the page fine, but when I try to insert into the database the information is scattered. Any recommendations?

Comment: I recommend a little bit more information on the issue, maybe some code and or schema.

Comment: do you mean that the parsed text is inserted to database ...it is scattered in the sense that it has spaces..end of lines and stuff? if so, you can use the `str_replace()` function

Comment: Scattered = HTML is not displayed correctly after an echo.

Comment: Are you trying to DISPLAY the HTML code itself, or are you trying to read in HTML to be parsed by the browser? In the former case you would use htmlentities; but in the latter case, you'd do nothing of the kind. In BOTH cases you should use mysql_real_escape_string before storing in the database, or escape your content with the appropriate method for your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what you mean, but may be functions like htmlspecialchars() and/or htmlentities() will help.

Answer (score 1):

use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

> — Escapes special characters in a
>   string for use in a SQL statement

```
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($html_code);
```

Comment: i know buddy! it's just a mistake! ;-)

Comment: IMHO, this is the BEST answer. `htmlentities()` and the like are for OUTPUT, not database input; what you want to do is mres the html content so that it comes out of the database exactly how it went in.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by scattered. Depending on the management tool, it may take on the HTML formatting. I have seen this in shared hosting servers where there is a web based management tool.

Make sure your are HTML encoding!